# What is the origin of けれど, ければ, けど, etc?

Tags: etymology, classical-japanese

In Classical Japanese (correct me if I'm wrong; all my CJ was from Wikipedia and linguistic papers), the 已然形 could attach a lot of things: ど, ば, ども, etc. So I would be able to say 会へども話せず rather than 会うけれど話せない?

Anyways, where does the `ker-` part come from in all these supplanted forms of the 已然形? Is there once some helping 四段 verb ける? If so, what would it mean?

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about, but can you clarify what ければ is?

Comment: The suffix ければ on 形容詞.

Comment: I was not clear enough.  By “clarify”, I meant “clarify by editing the question.”  By the way, I hope that by now you understand that けれど and ければ are syntactically quite different in Modern Japanese.

Comment: @user54609 〜けれ on adjectives is just the usual 已然形 suffix.

Comment: 会うけれど話せない=>会ふが話せず。会へども話せず=>会っても話せない。-- though I'm not certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are conjugational endings from (sh)i-Adjectives:

We can derive verbs from adjectives by adding あり:

> 赤し -> 赤く＋あり -> 赤かり

And conjugate them further:

- 赤かれ＋ば
- 赤けれ＋ど(も)
- 赤からず (negation)
- ...

This conjugational suffix got reanalyzed as a word on its own, yielding けれども, which was shortened to けれど, けども, and けど.

Even けれ by itself was used in the meaning of けれども by the same process.

日本国語大辞典

> けれ：この助詞が現れたのは、文語の形容詞の「数こそ多けれ、すぐれたるは少し」の_*「多けれ」のような用法から、「けれ」そのものに「が」「けれども」の意がある*_と考えたためであろうといわれる。〔徳川時代言語の研究=湯沢幸吉郎〕

Comment: Why is it 赤けれど rather than 赤かれば? あれど あれば seem to be the forms for あり, not えれど and あれば.

Comment: 赤く+あり->赤かり, but 赤く+あれど -> 赤けれど and 赤く+あれば-> 赤ければ

Comment: Yeah, why. Is there some sort of a/e alternation in Old Japanese?

Comment: Since no one has addressed the disagreement between the two answers, I'll try my best.  There are two similar looking things here, 形容詞活用の已然形語尾「けれ」 (described in this answer, apparently derived from く＋あれ, from which modern けれども・けれど and ultimately けど are derived) and 助動詞「けり」の已然形「けれ」 (mentioned in Tokyo Nagoya's answer, derived from き＋あり). According to [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E#.E5.8F.A4.E5.85.B8.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E8.AA.9E.E3.81.AE.E5.BD.A2.E5.AE.B9.E8.A9.9E.E3.81.AE.E6.B4.BB.E7.94.A8), 「く＋あれ」 also contracted to 「かれ」 in pre-Edo era Japanese.

Comment: @user54609 One book blutorange often quotes, Sansom's 1928 [*An Historical Grammar of Japanese*](https://archive.org/stream/historicalgramma00sansuoft#page/205/mode/2up), says on page 205: "This change is easy to understand, for the final *e* of *kare* influences the preceding vowel *a*, by a tendency which is common in Japanese."  (That's the only explanation I've found for けれ so far.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the auxiliary verb けり that you are discussing, not ける.  Or is it the origin of けり that you are trying to find out?  If so, I do not think anyone could answer.

Comment: What does けり mean? Sorry, as I said, I've never systematically learned CJ.

Comment: けり can express a few different things.
1. Restrospective heresay "Once upon a time, there lived a ~~~."   2. Equivalent of the present perfect progressive in English. "(Something) has been done this way for centuries."   3. Exclamatory.  "Oh, what a fool I have become!"   4. Objective statement of a fact.

Comment: Regarding けり, I believe there are two theories for its etymology: (1) The kahen verb ku "to come" in 連用形 plus ari, or (2) the recollective ki plus ari. (きあり⇒けり in both cases.) My understanding is that theory 1 is much accepted than 2.

Comment: And since it was not mentioned, けり is in its 已然形 for けれど, and ど is the concessive conjunctive particle.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, FWIW Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* lists the recollective き + あり as the first explanation, and 来{き} + あり as the second.